# Get value from key of parent and pass it to children key in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have structure like below:

```
{
  0: [{
    "id": "1",
    "parentId": "root",
    "path": "root"
    "children": [{
      "id": "2",
      "parentId": "1",
      "path": "1/2",
      "children": [
        "id": "4",
        "parentId": "2",
        "path": "2/4"
      ]
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "parentId": "1",
      "path": "1/3"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I have key `"path"` and now it's `"parentId/id"`, but I would like to have path from root to this element, so it should looks `"root/parentId/id/parentId/it..."` etc. For example path: `"root/1/2/4"`.

How can I dynamically put a value inside key `"path"` to get full path to root element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure does not respect the childhood of each element, but considering this is not a part of the question, here is a simple recursive solution:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "parentId": "root",
    "path": "root",
    "children": [{
        "id": "2",
        "parentId": "1",
        "path": "1/2",
        "children": [{
            "id": "4",
            "parentId": "2",
            "path": "2/4"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "parentId": "1",
        "path": "1/3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "parentId": "2",
    "path": "2/4"
  }
];

function assignPath(tree, index, array, currentPath) {
  tree.path = currentPath || 'root';
  tree.children && tree.children.forEach(child => {
    assignPath(child, null, null, `${tree.path}/${child.id}`);
  });
}

data.forEach(assignPath);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify the root node and start with its path.

Then add each consecutive child id to the path end.

```js
let obj = {
  0: [{
    "id": "1",
    "parentId": "root",
    "path": "root",
    "children": [{
      "id": "2",
      "parentId": "1",
      "path": "1/2",
      "children": [{
        "id": "4",
        "parentId": "2",
        "path": "2/4"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "parentId": "1",
      "path": "1/3"
    }]
  }]
};

console.log(getRoute(obj[0][0], true)); // Identify root

function getRoute(node, isRoot) {
  return node != null
    ? (isRoot
      ? (node.path + '/')
      : ''
    ) + node.id + (node.children
      ? '/' + getRoute(node.children[0], false)
      : '')
    : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution:

```
updatePath(array, 'root');

function updatePath(array, path) {
    array.forEach((element, i) => {
        element.path = path + '/' + (i + 1);
        if(element.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
           updatePath(element.children, element.path);
        } 
    });
}
```